# As a set is not assignment-compatible with a TValue, how do I represent a set using a TValue?

Tags: delphi, rtti

I have a string `'[Top,Left,Bottom,Right]'` that I want to convert to a set. For this I have the function `StringToSet` located in `System.TypInfo` But what I don't know is how I can assign the result of `StringToSet` to a `tvalue` (or any other way to convert `'[Top,Left,Bottom,Right]'` to a `tvalue`) ?

the code of the delphi StringToSet function:

```
function StringToSet(TypeInfo: PTypeInfo; const Value: string): Integer;
var
  P: PChar;
  EnumName: string;
  EnumValue: NativeInt;
  PEnumInfo: PPTypeInfo;

  // grab the next enum name
  function NextWord(var P: PChar): string;
  var
    i: Integer;
  begin
    i := 0;

    // scan til whitespace
    while not (P[i] in [',', ' ', #0,']']) do
      Inc(i);

    SetString(Result, P, i);

    // skip whitespace
    while (P[i] in [',', ' ',']']) do
      Inc(i);

    Inc(P, i);
  end;

begin
  Result := 0;
  if Value = '' then Exit;
  P := PChar(Value);

  // skip leading bracket and whitespace
  while (P^ in ['[',' ']) do
    Inc(P);

  PEnumInfo := GetTypeData(TypeInfo)^.CompType;
  if PEnumInfo <> nil then
  begin
    EnumName := NextWord(P);
    while EnumName <> '' do
    begin
      EnumValue := GetEnumValue(PEnumInfo^, EnumName);
      if EnumValue < 0 then
        raise EPropertyConvertError.CreateResFmt(@SInvalidPropertyElement, [EnumName]);
      Include(TIntegerSet(Result), enumvalue);
      EnumName := NextWord(P);
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    EnumName := NextWord(P);
    while EnumName <> '' do
    begin
      EnumValue := StrToIntDef(EnumName, -1);
      if EnumValue < 0 then
        raise EPropertyConvertError.CreateResFmt(@SInvalidPropertyElement, [EnumName]);
      Include(TIntegerSet(Result), enumvalue);
      EnumName := NextWord(P);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @MartynA iStringToSet is a Delphi Function, located in System.TypInfo

Comment: @MartynA yes sorry my question was not very well asked, i redo it now

Comment: I just noticed that Marco Cantu's D2010 book, p82, contains an example of reading the Anchors property of a TButton using TValue's ExtractRawData : the text of the book seems to be available online, but I'm not sure if it's a legal copy.  The same chapter also quotes Barry Kelly, who worked on the compiler saying "instances can be stored directly, as well as sets, class references, etc."